# Opencv saving empty video Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, video-streaming, video-capture

I am facing a problem in recording a video from camera. I am using python and opencv to do so. I have my images in QImage format, I convert them to numpy array in order to display to stream it when video capturing of the cam (using VideoCapture of opencv), everything works fine.
When I try to record a video and save it in the folder (using VideoWriter_fourcc of opencv), I get no errors but I get an empty video. I did a lot of searching to find the problem but I couldn't.
Here's the code that I use to record a video:

```py
import cv2

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G')  
#img is a numpy array  
videoWriter = cv2.VideoWriter('video.avi', fourcc, 20,  (img.shape[0],img.shape[1]))
while True:
    videoWriter.write(img)
videoWriter.release()
```

I tried to change the Framerate, the frameSize, the extension of the video and the code of codec but nothing worked.
I am so desperate. I appreciate all and every help and suggestion I can get.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you **mixed up width and height** as you passed them to VideoWriter.

`VideoWriter` wants `(width, height)` for the `frameSize` argument.

Note that `width = img.shape[1]` and `height = img.shape[0]`

Giving VideoWriter a, say, 1920x1080 frame to write, while having promised 1080x1920 frames in the constructor, will fail, but silently.

Comment: I tried it, it didn't change a thing. But thanks for your answer

Comment: if that "didn't change a thing", there's more wrong with your code. what I wrote is definitely _an issue_, but perhaps not the only one. you must present a [mre], not just pseudocode.